# Wrap with column not showing in context menu in Android Studio Flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to learn flutter, but I keep getting problems not with the code, but with the behaviour of the IDEs.   I've spent considerably more time (feels like at least 10x the amount) trying to fix issues that actually have nothing to do with the code.

My current problem is that I've seen several tutorials where the instructor highlights the scaffold widget in code, right clicks and goes 'wrap with Column'.  That option simply isn't there for me, so I'm having trouble following the guide.

I even tried to do this with the shortcut ctrl+. in VScode, and that doesn't show me a wrap column option either.  I could just write the code manually, copying what happens when the instructor uses the context menu, but I feel I shouldn't have to.  Any ideas?

[Here is what the instructor sees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpKV2.jpg)

[And here is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZu5M.jpg)

Answer (score 12):

Just make sure **Scope analysis to the current package** in **Dart Analysis Server Settings** is checked.

1. Just at the bottom of Android Studio, go to Dart Analysis -> Analyser Settings
2. Check **Scope analysis to the current package**

[Check the image here for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRHSI.png)

Comment: The image for illustration

Comment: wow bro, thats great. thanks for sharing this tip.

Comment: Thank you so much, this did it for me! Impossible to work without the wrap tool.

Comment: This is perfect for the one, who tried everything else but nothing worked!!!!

Answer (score 6):

Put your cursor at the last letter of the widget name.

For example:

```
child: TextFormField(
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
```

to show "Wrap with column or row menu" put your cursor at the last character of TextFormField. (between d letter and "(")

[wrap with column will show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79XFw.png)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it turns out you need to only right-click the widget name and not highlight the widget and then right click.  Wrap in column showed as soon as I did this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!
All I had to do is:

1. Go to Preferences -> Editor -> Intentions.
2. Then search for "Dart".
3. Enable the "Quick assists powered by Dart Analysis".

[image: screenshot of setting]

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing similar problem while doing Kotlin programming for Android Studio and I was just missing the step of clicking on the Light Bulb.